# jQuery combine selectors

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I combine this two selectors:

```
$("td.listas select:last option:selected")
```

This doesn't work!

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Get the **select** input from a **td** with the class **listas**
- Get the **option** that is **selected**

**Notes:**

- In this **td**, I have two **select** inputs.

**Code working:**

```
    var selectprimeiro = $('td.listas select:first');
    var selectsegundo = $('td.listas select:last option');
    selectsegundo.prop("selected",true);
    var selected = $("td.listas select:last option:selected");
    selected.each(function(){
        selectprimeiro.append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        selected.remove();
    });
```

Comment: I see only one selector. Anyways, questions about selectors should be complemented with markup and an explanation which elements you want to select, since this is what selectors do: Select elements.

Comment: Are you trying to select the selected option of the last `select` element in a `td` with class `listas`?

Comment: If you have control of the html give each select an id. It'll make things much simpler

Comment: Btw, your selector does "work": http://jsfiddle.net/4m3jG/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
var lastSelectedOptionElement = $("td.listas select option:selected").last();
```

First you get all of the selected options, then you take the last of them. [Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/uharot) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uharot/edit)

You might be tempted to do `option:last:selected`, but that won't work (unless the last option in the list happens to be selected), because the `option` would have to be *both* `:last` *and* `:selected`.

---

**Update**:

Re your edit:

> In this td, I have two select inputs.

If they are not multi-select `select` elements, to get the selected `option` element:

```
opt = $("td.listas select:first option:selected"); // The first one
// or
opt = $("td.listas select:last option:selected");  // The last one -- this is your original selector
```

If they are multi-select, combine the two techniques above:

```
// The *last* selected option in the *first* select list:
opt = $("td.listas select:first option:selected").last();

// The *last* selected option in the *last* select list:
opt = $("td.listas select:last option:selected").last();

// The *first* selected option in the *first* select list:
opt = $("td.listas select:first option:selected").first();

// The *first* selected option in the *last* select list:
opt = $("td.listas select:last option:selected").first();
```

Comment: @silentw: Are the multi-select? What is the actual end value you're looking for? It's unclear.

Comment: Should this not be equivalent the to selector the OP has (as long as it is not multi-select)? Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/4m3jG/1/. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: There was a typo in my code. I need to get the second select in a variable, so I could prop to select all. I was missing the `option`

Comment: @FelixKling: Their selector gets the selected option of the last `select` box. It wasn't at all clear from the original question that that was what they wanted. My (first) selector does something different: In a multi-select box, it gets the *last* of the selected options (from what I presumed, in the absense of any data to the contrary, was the only `select` box). It's still completely unclear to me what the OP wants, in light of their edit. I've scattershot it above. :-)

Comment: @silentw: It's still unclear: What are you actually trying to get? In your comment you've said you want the select (nothing to do with options), but I'm afraid the phrase *"...so I could prop to select all"* is unclear to me.

Comment: @silentw: I still don't get it, but if this solved the problem, great! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector looks correct, where you might be going wrong is getting the value, you just need to add `.val()` on the end of it.

```
var lastSelVal = $("td.listas select:last option:selected").val();
```

**Rough demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/4m3jG/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/4m3jG/4/)